# Bibtex errors "Environment thebibliography undefined"

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I'm trying to get the simplest code to work to try bibtex but I can't figure it out dispite following tutorials/searching. I'm using texmaker and I'm quite new to this.

I get these messages:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment thebibliography undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{thebibliography}
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{thebibliography}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{thebibliography}
Citation `DUMMY:1' on page 1 undefined
There were undefined references.
```

This is my document: `expose.tex`:

```
\bibliography{lesson7a1} 
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}   
\begin{document}

\section{Text goes here} 

This feature works as I described in \cite{DUMMY:1}

\end{document}

\printbibliography
```

In the same folder I have a file called `lesson7a1.bib` which looks like this:

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
YEAR="2100",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tom. You need to cut the contents of bibliography and paste the same just before the \end{document} environment. Moreover, remove the \printbibliography from the preamble. This can be done as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}   
\begin{document}

\section{Text goes here}. 

This feature works as I described in \cite{DUMMY:1}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{lesson7a1} 

\end{document}
```